# Fetch the Username from another mongoose library efficiently

Tags: node.js, mongoose

how can I fetch the Users Schema `username` easily when rendering a table which displays all products and for each product the user who owns the product (username).

For some reason, I get back nothing instead of the `return user.username`.

When rendering 1000 products into a table and asking from the database the User schema 1000 times is pretty inefficient. What's a better approach for it? I'm using handlebars to render the table and mongoose to query the data.

User model:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

Product model:

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  amount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  ownerID: {
    //The ID of Users model
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

Handlebars code (Table row part. Im looping trough all my products):

```
<td>{{returnProductsOwner this.ownerID}}</td>
<td>{{this.name}}</td>
<td>{{this.amount}}</td>
```

ReturnProductsOwner:

```
returnProductsOwner: function(id) {
      User.findById(id).then((user) => {
        return user.username;
      }).catch();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using no-sql database why are you saving user details separately? No-sql db doesnt handle joins very well. So what you can do is store the User details with the product details itself so you will be able to query it faster and efficently.

Comment: But when the user decides to change the password, then I have to update each product, there might be 100000 of those? Or changes their username?

Comment: Then why don't you go with a relational database? It will solve your problem. Because by seeing your model I don't see a need of no-sql database.

Comment: Is there any other way than storing the user details with the product details or using SQL? A handlebars helper function?

Comment: How would the task look when using SQL?

Comment: Join the 2 tables and return an array to front end and iterate over it to get the username.

Comment: And https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/01/sql-vs-nosql-db/ will tell you why I was telling you to go for sql after getting a brief of your requirements

Comment: I found out somehow, that there was a really easy way in mongoose and that was `.populate('ownerID')` after using that, I can now access the other document fields as well.